# Use of " for(string str: tmp) " in c++?

Tags: java, c++, string

I came accross this `for(string str: tmp) s.insert(str)` in a C++ code for LCS and I don't know what it means. I saw it used in Java. Can it be written in any other way in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is know as a for-each. It'll iterate over the different elements of a data structure (for instance, a list, a vector, a set, ...), allowing you to perform some operations on each elements. If you want to use it in c++ you will have to use c++11, but you can reach a similar behavior with an iterator based `for` loop.

Going with your `for (string str : tmp) s.insert(str)`, here is a small description of each parts of the expression. `tmp` is the data structure over which you want to iterate. `string str` is the declaration that will be called for each elements in the data structure. The type declared should reflect what is in the data structure. This `str` variable will give you access to the data structure's item in the loop's "body". The last part of the expression `s.insert(str)` is the loop's "body" as in any regular `for` loop, but the coder chose to put it on the same line as the `for`.

In short, that loop inserts all the strings contained in `tmp` inside an object `s` with an `insert` method, probably another data structure.

Comment: I understand it now.Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
for(string str: tmp) s.insert(str)
```

is a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

It can be rewritten as

```
for (auto it = std::begin(tmp); it != std::end(tmp); ++it) s,insert(*it);
```

and dozens of other ways with a variety of different types of loops. If the type of `tmp` is known it can possibly be simplified further.

[Documentation on `std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin)

[Documentation on `std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end)

Answer (score 0):

The latest C++ version has a similar `for-each` loop. You would need to compile your program with the latest version of C++ for it to function correctly.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Please can you explain a bit? I mean about how this works.

Comment: It's just a basic for-loop, as the reference material states, "Used as a more readable equivalent to the traditional for loop operating over a range of values, such as all elements in a container."

So in the case of your for-each loop, for-each str in the container tmp, insert the str (string) into s

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small working example in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> tmp = { "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"};

    std::vector<std::string> s;

    for (const std::string& str : tmp)
        s.insert(s.end(),str);

    return 0;
}
```

Here, `tmp` and `s` are vectors of string

So we are copying the content of the vector `tmp` to the `s` vector

The for loop: **`for (const std::string& str : tmp)`** will take every value from the `tmp` vector and insert it (append it) to the end of the `s` vector.

This for loop is called a [range based loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) **(since C++11)**

Comment: Should be `for (const std::string& str : tmp)` to avoid unneccessary copying.

Comment: I know that, I just removed it to keep the example as similar as to the example given in the question to not to confuse more @annzi.